# Is there a way to have a number format in RTF Template

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I have 2 different column to total using the RTF Template. I got the total of the 2 column but the problem is the format I got is not what I expected. Is there a way to have a number format using the XML tags or there's other way to do? Thanks.

My XML Tag to get the total is,

`<?xdofx:to_number(1639.71)+to_number(118.66)?>`

and the output is

`1758.3700000000001`

and the output I want should be,

`1,758.37`

I tried this one but I got `0`

`<?xdofx:to_number(1639.71,’#,##0.00)+to_number(118.66,’#,##0.00)?>`

Comment: Have you tried `<?1639.71+118.66?>`? That works fine for me. You are not closing the apostrophes on the format strings. `(1639.71,’#,##0.00)` -> `(1639.71,'#,##0.00')`But anyway, you'd want to set the format after the sum, in your code, you do it before.

Comment: Do you have Oracle Support? Doc ID 654949.1 states that there is/was a bug with number formats and sums. It advises to use round instead.

Comment: I'm just here to laugh that A) this is a horrendous bug and B) Oracle provides a workaround rather than fixing a simple and reproducible bug. LOL I'd open an SR and fight this with every last breath if I was paying the license fees.